# Postman, schema validation

Tags: postman

It should be easy, but...

```
var response = pm.response.json();

    var schema = {
        "username": {
            "type":"string"
        },
        "password": {
            "type":"string"
        },
        "date": {
             "type":"string"
        }
    };

    pm.test('Schema is valid', function() {
      pm.expect(tv4.validate(response, schema)).to.be.true;
    });
```

- the response from rest api is:

> {
>           "username": "test@test.pl",
>           "password": "asdasdsadasd",
>           "date": "2019-07-05T12:09:40"
>       }

But always the result test is passed. Event I initialized empty schema = {}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"But always the result test is passed"*

That's because the schema syntax is incorrect. To get the expected result, the schema should be:

```
var schema = {
    type: "object",
    properties: {
        "username": {
            "type":"string"
        },
        "password": {
            "type":"string"
        },
        "date": {
             "type":"string"
        }
    }

};
```

Then, if you change the `type` of `username` or `password` or `date` (`integer` for example), the schema validation test would fail (expected result).